# How to set constraints on multi line labels within a tableview cell

Tags: objective-c

I have 4 custom labels inside a custom Tableview cell. The tabelview cell's height is a fixed number.

I am setting the auto layout constraints of the labels programatically.

I've allowed the labels to be as tall as the content inside the labels (NumberOfLines=0).

I've set the width constraints correctly and I've also set the padding constraints inside a loop like so:

```
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previousLabel]-20-[customLabel]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(customLabel, previousLabel)]];
```

Everything is laid out correctly except when one OR more of the labels have too much content and they overflow into the next cell.

I want to programatically add constraints (I think it might be compression resistance and content hugging values) so that the labels stop at the end of their tableview cell.

====

Here is the code where I setup some of the constraints:

```
for (UIView *subView in cell.contentView.subviews) {
 if ([subView isKindOfClass:[AFRCustomLabel class]]) {
  customLabel = (AFRCustomLabel *)subView;
  if (!previousLabel) {
   [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-40-[customLabel]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(customLabel)]];
  } else {
   [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previousLabel]-20-[customLabel]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(customLabel, previousLabel)]];
  }
  previousLabel = customLabel;
  [cell.contentView addConstraints:constraints];
 }
}
```

Here is a screen shot of the label's text overflowing. Keep in mind 2 labels could overflow.

[image]

Comment: May be constraint should be like that: `V:|[previousLabel]-20-[customLabel]|`?

Comment: This adds a constraint for every custom label to the bottom of the superview, which isn't correct

Comment: Ok. Did you add vertical border constraints anyway?

Comment: Added the rest of my code. Maybe that will help? Only the bottom constraint(s) are needed.

Comment: Add `V:[previousLabel]-40-|` after for loop.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't stop the labels' text from going over to the next cell